# Extended SeekBar (Custom View) not showing

Tags: java, android, android-view, seekbar

In my main layout xml file I have this:

```
<view class="com.mysite.MainActivity$MySeekBar"
     android:id="@+id/seekBar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And in MainActivity.java inside the MainActivity class I have this:

```
public static class MySeekBar extends SeekBar {
    public MySeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
}
```

In the above case, nothing displays. However it does work if instead of the first snippet I have this:

```
 <SeekBar
     android:id="@+id/seekBar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I have also tried using uppercase 'View' instead of 'view' in the xml.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I have tried following [this google developer page on custom components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) which at the bottom gives a simple example of implementing with an inner class.

Comment: you are missing two constructors and your view should start something like this <com.mysite.MainActivity$MySeekBar/>

Comment: @IllegalArgument, thanks - but see my edit - the link shows that for an inner class, it should start: <view class="... which two constructors am I missing?

Comment: MySeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) and MySeekBar(Context context) different constructors are called based on the java code or xml you define. Just for debugging prupose set 50dp width and height and a background

Comment: Thank you, I have tried what you said. But I want MySeekBar to have the same GUI as SeekBar, so why isn't it doing that? I have set width, height and background as you suggested, and the background appears, but that is all?

Answer (score 0):

put this class in its own file

```
   <com.mypackagename.MySeekBar <== this is missing
         android:id="@+id/seekBar"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: From what I have read, it is definitely possible to do this as an inner class